# How do I determine the coordinates of controls in a WM_INITDIALOG message?

Tags: winapi

I am having troubles to determine the (what I believe to be the) client coordinates
of a (radio button) control in the `WM_INITDIALOG` message of a `DlgProc`.

Here's what I try:

```
// Retrieve coordinates of Control with respect to the screen.
RECT rectOrthoButton;
GetWindowRect(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_ORTHO), &rectOrthoButton);

// Translate coordinates to more useful coordinates: those that
// are used on the dialog.
// In order to do the translation we have to find the top left
// point (coordinates) of the dialog's client:
POINT dlgTopLeft;
ClientToScreen(hWnd, &dlgTopLeft);

// With these coordinates we can do the translation.
// We're only interested in top and left, so we skip
// bottom and right:
rectOrthoButton.top    -= dlgTopLeft.y;
rectOrthoButton.left   -= dlgTopLeft.x;

use_top_and_left(rectOrthoButton.top, rectOrthoButton.left);
```

I expected `rectOrthoButton.top` and `.left` to be the top left coordinates of my control *with respect to the dialog's client area*. It turns out they aren't and I am not sure
what they point to as `rectOrthoButton.left` is equal to -40.

**Edit**: Now that I was directed to initialize the POINT with

```
POINT dlgTopLeft = {0, 0};
```

(which I *stupidly* forgot): Is there a shorter way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Shouln't you put '0' to dlgTopLeft.x/y before calling ClientToScreen?

Comment: Yes, that did it! Now, if you made an answer I could tick your answer as *correct* (or whatever that tick is named). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a Point to screen coordinates, the Point should contain the client coordinates (0, 0 in case of client origin) before passing to [`ClientToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).